# scrollmagic how to off 'update' event when fire 'progress' event

Tags: scrollmagic

now I want to listen somewhere out of 'progress' event.(between red line and blue line)[scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amugg.png)

I know that 'update' event can listen it, but the 'progress' event will also listen it.

```
.on('update', function (e) {
    console.log('=== update 1111');
})
.on('progress', function (e) {
    console.log('progress === 2222');
    scene2.off('update', function(){
        console.log('===================');
    });
})
```

I try to use 'off' func,but it makes no sense.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry，
(between red line and blue line)  => (between red line and green line) 

the red line is the 'end' of the prev section

the green line is the 'start' of the next section

the blue line is the 'trigger'